# How to apply plugin in a "live" fashion

Tags: jquery, cluetip

Is there a way to apply plugin to element in a "live" fashion, just like we can attach handler that survives ajax calls? Right now we have some code that uses "cluetip" in a rad grid, but after ajax, it gets dropped.

```
$('a.clickableSticky').cluetip({
                    splitTitle: '|',
                    showTitle: false,
                    titleAttribute: 'description',
                    activation: 'click',
                    sticky: true,
                    arrows: true,
                    closePosition: 'title'
                });
```

Comment: I edited my answer with some options. :)

Answer (score 1):

Live only works on events, so you can't do it with clue tip.

You can still run cluetip on any newly created elements though.

So...

```
$('#grid').live('gridRefreshEvent', function () {
 $('#grid').find('a.clickableSticky').cluetip({ splitTitle: '|', showTitle: false, titleAttribute: 'description', activation: 'click', sticky: true, arrows: true, closePosition: 'title' });
}
```

Edit:

If the plugin doesn't provide an event, you can hack the plugin to create your own event by finding the ajax function in their code and adding:
`$('#grid').trigger('gridRefreshEvent');` somewhere.

You can also try asking RadGrid support about the event. Any non-dumb dev would add basic things like this.

Comment: problem is that I have not clue what that 'gridRefereshEvent' is on RadGrid. God, do I hate RadGrid based solutions.